# How to validate Ajax data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I wondering how can I validate, and be sure that when I am use (jQuery) ajax the data that the server gets is really what the client send.
In other words i want to verify the data in the server side (asp.net mvc) and prevent data leak and security risks.

Thanks alot,

Gal

Comment: validate the model when it is filled: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/216439/Data-Validation-Using-Annotations-for-jQuery-Ajax

Comment: but still someone can read the packet or see what i sent to the server and copy it/send identical data/etc...i wnat to be sure 100% that i can trust the data

Comment: that is what the server side validation is....no matter what you receive...you must validate it a t the backend